# Cannot Open Dev Menu on Xiaomi Devices

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using `react-native-cli` for making a React Native App. It is working fine, and successfully installs on my connected Device but I cannot open the **Dev Menu** on it.

There is no hardware Menu button, and the `shake device` ain't working too.

Is there any other way to open the Dev menu?

Or is this bug specific to Xiaomi devices and dev menu cannot be opened on MI?

Phone: Mi Note 3
React Native: 0.39.2

Comment: Have you tried `adb shell input keyevent 82`?

Comment: Disable the permission manager.

Comment: @SatanPandeya Drop a nuke to kill a fly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For xiaomi devices, you need to enable popup permission from `security->permissions->app name -> popup`

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2754#issuecomment-140815500

Comment: you save my day

Answer (score 10):

On my Redmi 4X i need to hold the "menu" button to open The Dev Menu options.

To verify this option, you can go to:
**Settings --> Additional config --> Buttons and gestures shortcuts --> Show menu**

PS: As **palaniraja** said, you need to enable popup permission as well.

Comment: This help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to open dev menu on Mi Box? It does not have menu button.

Answer (score 5):

I get Xiaomi Mi 8 and, after many hours I have discovered how show the dev menu.

The problem, in this device, is that when you send the command:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

is the same that perform a click "menu button" on device.

In brief, if you want to show dev menu on newest devices with miui, you must perform a "**long click**" on the menu button (NOT A "SIMPLE CLICK")

All the best!

Comment: this worked for me, on Note 6 model running Android 8

Comment: @JUANM4 where do you do this long press?  on which icon?

Comment: I can't open menu in xiaomi 9A, any sulution that?

Comment: @ueeieiie there should three icons at the bottom of the screen. Usually, it's "square" - "circle" - "triangle". So you need to just press and hold the "square" icon. Worked for me on Xiaomi MI 9T pro.

Answer (score 4):

While the device is connected (check `adb devices -l`), you can use the command:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU
```

Answer (score 0):

I got strange behavior, when yesterday it worked fine, but today is not working. To fix it,- i restarted device and it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enable the ***Display pop-up window***

**Settings** > **Permissions** > **Permissions**

[image]